# Can't upload deck on Anki with "malformed deck package" error

Tags: upload

I'm struggling with uploading my own deck to Anki. I found that when I tried uploading my deck on [this page](https://api.ankiapp.com/nexus/), it always got me the error "Malformed deck package".

So I tried downloading [styled_impord](https://ankiapp.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/5000051548-can-i-import-decks-from-spreadsheets-tsv-csv-) from their official site, and open it, then compress it again with the following command, but got the same error.

```
zip -r -X new_import.zip styled_import
```

What made the error happening? Is this a bug? Or maybe am I wrong with compressing the deck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out that `zip` command on macOS does not work in other platforms, and Anki must not use mac on its server.

So instead of `zip`, use `ditto` command [as written in this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/102467/54787):

```
ditto -ck --norsrc directory directory.zip
```

And the import finally succeeded.

Comment: Thanks! it worked.